# Serialize an Entity Framework Entity that has child Collections

Tags: c#, entity-framework, serialization, windows-store-apps

I have a Windows Store app.  I am trying to save the state when the system does a suspend and shutdown.  I am serializing an Estimate Object which was generated by Entity Framework 6.  It has Child Entities that are stores in DataServiceCollections in the Estimate Entity.  When I deserialize it, I get the following error:

An item could not be added to the collection. When items in a DataServiceCollection are tracked by the DataServiceContext, new items cannot be added before items have been loaded into the collection.

The Serialization functions I am using are:

```
        public static string SerializeObject(object obj)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType(), Common.SuspensionManager.KnownTypes);
        ser.WriteObject(stream, obj);
        byte[] data = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(data);
    }

    public static T DeserializeObject<T>(string input)
    {
        System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(input));
        return (T)ser.ReadObject(stream);
    }
```

The calls to these functions are as follows:

Serialize in the save state:

```
 e.PageState["SelectedEstimate"] = StringSerializer.SerializeObject(Est);
```

Deserialize in the Restore State:

```
Est = StringSerializer.DeserializeObject<Estimate>((string)e.PageState["SelectedEstimate"]);
```

Is there a better Serialization method that can be used with EF Entities?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was posted a while back, but I figure it deserves and answer.  The answer is to not use Entity Framework and just create your own entities.  I used ObservableCollections for the child members of my entity.  One thing that EF does for you is track the state.  You can do this yourself by adding the enumeration in your WCF Interface definition:

```
[DataContract(Name = "RecordState")]
public enum CustomerRecordStateEnum
{
    [EnumMember]
    Unchanged = 0,
    [EnumMember]
    Added = 1,
    [EnumMember]
    Modified = 2,
    [EnumMember]
    Deleted = 3
}
```

Then in the Customer or whatever object have a Property for RecordState.

```
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<CustomerRecordStateEnum> RecordState { get; set; }
```

In your WCF where you generate the object, initialize it to unchanged.  In your client, the generated objects will implement IPropertyChanged.  You can hook this and set the state to modified.  You only want to do this if nothing else has been done to it.  If it has been added or deleted and you change the state to modified, things get messy:

```
    void Cust_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName != "RecordState")
        {
            if (Cust.RecordState == RecordState.Unchanged)
                Cust.RecordState = RecordState.Modified;
        }
    }
```

After you create your class Cust use:

```
        Cust.PropertyChanged += Cust_PropertyChanged;
```

The only thing to remember is that if from your app, you update the object (Cust in this case) be sure to set the RecordState back to RecordState.Unchanged.

The whole point of this is that using this scenario you can create entities that keep track of their record state and also serialize them when you need to save the state for a suspension or otherwise.  They will deserialize just fine.  That way, on a resume, you are not loading them from the service.  Loading them from the service would overwrite any changes you had made locally but hadn't saved yet.

Hope this is useful to someone.

Jim